# AWS CloudWatch Rule triggered by Log Event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create CloudWatch Rule that would be triggered upon creation of Log Event. For that reason as an event pattern I selected CloudWatch Logs service but when I try to generate some Cloud Watch logs the rule is not getting triggered. I can not find any example of using aws.logs as a source for an event and hence my question if I'm doing something wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the only events for `logs` available are **AWS API Call via CloudTrail**. CloudWatch Logs does not generate CloudWatch events on receiving new log entries.

For the Logs API call events to work, you need to setup [CloudTrial trial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-and-update-a-trail.html).

However, if you want to trigger your lambda function based on log entries, I can recommend using [subscription filters for lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html):

> You can use subscriptions to get access to a **real-time feed of log events** from CloudWatch Logs and have it delivered to other services such as a Amazon Kinesis stream, Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose stream, or **AWS Lambda** for custom processing, analysis, or loading to other systems.